# Python Connect to AWS Aurora Serverless MySQL Using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aws-secrets-manager, pandas-to-sql, aws-aurora-serverless

Is there a way to specify my connection with SQLAlchemy to an AWS RDS Aurora Serverless MySQL database instance without a Secrets Manager ARN? I have the database username, password, endpoint, ARN, etc., and ideally I would initialize an engine, then use `df.to_sql()` to load a DataFrame into a table on the Aurora instance.

```
...
else:
   engine = create_engine([WHAT DO I SPECIFY HERE?])
   with engine.connect() as conn:
      df.to_sql([CODE TO APPEND TO EXISTING TABLE HERE])...
```

Comment: Did you create a secret in aws secrets manager that contains the database username, password, etc?

Comment: Yep! Have a secret ARN as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Alchemy documentation - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html, this is what the connect string should look like - the parameter in create_engine - for MySQL

```
mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<host>/<dbname>[?<options>]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- in the context of an AWS RDS Aurora Serverless MySQL instance, how would this look? <username> = database instance username, <password> = database instance password, <host> = database instance endpoint?, what are options? Why do I need pymysql in the prefix?

Comment: I think you need pymysql because sqlalchemy is a Python SQL toolkit and pymysql is the python mysql client

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can connect to Aurora without a secrets ARN, but if you are willing to use one, you could install a driver like this: https://github.com/koxudaxi/py-data-api

Which would allow you to do something like the following:

```
def example_driver_for_sqlalchemy():
    from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
    engine = create_engine(
        'mysql+pydataapi://',
        connect_args={
            'resource_arn': 'arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster:dummy',
            'secret_arn': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:dummy',
            'database': 'test'
        }
    )
    result: ResultProxy = engine.execute("select * from pets")
    print(result.fetchall())
```